# Using php as a medium between client and server app

Tags: java, php, sockets

I have a tablet app which is able to connect to a mobile phone using the local wifi network which both devices are connected to.

My problem is bluetooth is not an available api on the tablet currently so i would like to test out using my server as a medium for when im out and about.

I would like to know if this kind of flow is possible in php?

I want to make a socket connection to php

The php code will then call another php page on the server to make a push message to the phone device

The phone device will then connect to my server and transfer images (screen captures) up to the server via socket connection as fast as it can

The server will then write this data to the other socket connection (tablet)

Ambitious - certainly, but is it possible?

I am a complete beginner in php but have been coding with java for a couple of years now. Is it too much to expect to find a similar example somewhere?

Thanks for any help you can provide

Comment: Hey checkout this tutorial: http://devzone.zend.com/article/1086.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yeah that's possible, you can transfer data by cURL (http://www.php.net/curl), socket can be used too, But i think it's best that your tablet send a request for ex each 30secs to server to see if there is anything new to download. and also your mobile can do the same, and if there was any new images to upload, so program it to upload..